# Qt Drag and Drop option's url not coming

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt, and I'm trying to add "drag and drop" option using `QListWidget`. Here's my code for drop event:

```
void hello::dropEvent(QDropEvent * event)
{
    QString numberArch;
    QList<QUrl> urls;
    QList<QUrl>::Iterator i;
    event->mimeData()->urls();
    for(i=urls.begin(); i != urls.end(); i++)
    {
        numberArch = i->fileName();
        ui->listWidget->addItem(numberArch);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show all d'n'd-related methods you implemented. Problem in either one can cause whole d'n'd not working.

Comment: As general recommendations I would suggest you to read your code, then do [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), then perform normal [debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) with a debugger (fortunately Qt comes with IDE and good [debugging UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)), before you ask another person to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your `urls` (optimally in one statement):

```
QList<QUrl> urls = event->mimeData()->urls();
```

`event->mimeData()->urls();` alone does nothing, remove it.

In addition, you should initialize your iterator in the loop or use `q_foreach` or C++11's range-for.